# PySpark equivalent of LAST_INSERT_ID()

Tags: jdbc, pyspark

In Spark 2.2.0 I am succesfully using `df.jdbc.write` to append records to an existent MySQL table:

```
    mysql_uri = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb"
    uri = mysql_uri + "?rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
    table = "test"
    properties = {
        "user": "user",
        "password": "pass"
    }
    df.write.jdbc(url=uri, table=table, mode="append", properties=properties)
```

Table `test` has an AUTO_INCREMENT `Id` field. Say my dataframe `df` has only one row, is there any way of getting back the last row `Id` once its inserted?

Comment: Can you do `SELECT max(Id) FROM test`?

Comment: @pault I can, but its not guaranteed that eventually another row has been inserted between my 1st append and the SELECT max()